# JFace wizard root category

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-rap

How to create a wizard that will be display on the same level and "New interface", "new class", "New java project" etc.

I was using category id **org.eclipse.pde.PDE** but seems it doesn't work and all the time my wizard appears into "Others" folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done using the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` to define a 'new wizard shortcut' for a particular perspective.

For example:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
     <newWizardShortcut
           id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.wizards.NewTestCaseCreationWizard">
     </newWizardShortcut>
  </perspectiveExtension>
```

Is the definition for the JUnit new test case shortcut.

Shortcuts defined like this can be turned on or off on the 'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective' dialog in the 'Shortcuts' tab.

More details in the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html)

Note: You may have to Reset the perspective or use the Customize Perspective dialog to get the new shortcut to show up if the perspective has already been used.

Comment: Id form newWizardShortcut is a wizard id?

Comment: Yes, it is the id of your new wizard.